# Selenium => 4BUTTON with same href , same class , same text wanna click on 4

Tags: selenium, class, text, href

I just tried to find element on website but can't find it .Code is :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default free_send_button">Basla</a>
```

Could you help me about it . There is a 4 same html button codes : 4 same href , 4 same class , 4 same text code... I just wanna click on 4. I tried some codes i wrote'em below . Can you fix my codes if its possible and usefull or which way to find element is best way to do it ? Thanks already..

```
self.web.find_element_by_xpath("(//href[text()[contains(.,'#')]])[1]").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the class and the text also same and you want to click on the last/fourth match then you can try the below locators :

```
locator = "(//a[text()='Basla'])[last()]"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
element.click()
```

or

```
locator = "(//a[text()='Basla'])[4]"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
element.click()
```

or

```
locator = "(//a[contains(@class, 'free_send_button')])[last()]"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
element.click()
```

or

```
locator = "(//a[contains(@class, 'free_send_button')])[4]"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
element.click()
```

You can write some more xpaths for that locator but I think above mentioned will work.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Ali CSE .. Can you explain that , why are we using "a" front before contains ? Is that mean all ?

Comment: `a` is an html node there... you want to identify an element which is present inside the html `a` tag right so used `a` there... You can replace that with `*` also but in this case you will have multiple matches...

Comment: Thanks for answering and explaining mate !

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to go on class'name and found it .I hope it might be helpful:

```
self.web.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-default free_send_button')])[1]").click()
```